# i18n not working on custom error pages

Tags: symfony, twig

I've created templates for error pages in app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception. But I have a problem with translations on these pages, i.e.

```
<h3>{{ 'error_page.404.header'|trans({}, 'ProjCoreBundle') }}</h3>
```

not working. My translations are in src/Proj/CoreBundle/Resources/translations/ProjCoreBundle.%lang%.yml, where %lang% means locale (i.e. "en") and they are working fine on other pages. What may cause a problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I mean it just returns translation id, in this case `error_page.404.header`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the necessary overrides in the proper directory. In this case in the top level directories `app/Resources/TwigBundle/translations` or in `app/Resources/translations` folder (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations).

> Symfony looks for message files (i.e. translations) in the following
>   locations:
>
> > - the app/Resources/translations directory;
> > - the app/Resources//translations directory
> > - the Resources/translations/ directory inside of any bundle.
>
> The locations are listed here with the highest
>   priority first. That is, you can override the translation messages of
>   a bundle in any of the top 2 directories.

To use a override parts of another bundle inside your own, you need inherit your bundle from the second one:
See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html

```
class AcmeUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

> By making this simple change, you can now override several parts of
>   the FOSUserBundle simply by creating a file with the same name.

Also, if you're using Symfony 2.5 see the debug mechanism that were introduced in this version.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've just created `TwigBundle.uk.yml` file with my translations in `app/Resources/TwigBundle/translations`, and added to template `{{ 'error.404.header'|trans({}, 'TwigBundle') }}`, but translations are still not found. Where am I wrong?